# Add marker to google map, reference map but don't reinstantiate it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When trying to add a marker, the map goes grey screen. I have narrowed it down to the `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);` line. I got a map with an id of `map` and When the user selects a location from the search bar, that location must be added to the map in form of a pin / marker.

```
function mezmerize(address, lat, lon) {

$('#myPlaceTextBox').val("");
var latlong = getLatLong(address);
var location_html = '<li class="location" data-location="'+address+'">'+
    '<span class="title">'+address+' </span>'+
    '<span class="" onclick="deleteMe()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="chosen_location[]" value="'+address+'">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="latitude[]" value="'+lat+'">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="longitude[]" value="'+lon+'">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="address[]" value="'+address+'">'+
    '</li>';

$(".interests_wrapper").append(location_html);
console.log(address);
console.log(lat + "," + lon);
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat + "," + lon);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: myLatlng
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: address
});

var optOptions = {
    urlBase: '/codeigniter/ads2trade/',
    showRadii: true,
    currentFilterCriteria: {},
    showSearchPOIButton: true,
    showFilterButton: true,
    showLegend: false
};
var clusterOptions = {};
var spiderOptions = {};
var html2canvasOptions = {
    logging: false
};

var adsMap = new AdsMap(map, clusterOptions, spiderOptions, html2canvasOptions, optOptions);

adsMap.addMarker(marker);

}
//
function getLatLong(address){

var lattitude = "0";
var longitude = "0";

$.ajax({
    url:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+address+"&sensor=false",
    type: "POST",
    success:function(res){
        lattitude = res.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        longitude = res.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        //console.log(lattitude);
        //console.log(longitude);
        return lattitude + ',' + longitude;
    },
    error: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
}
```

[image: On Create]

[image: When creating a new map]

Any ideas how to fix this and add the marker?

Comment: 1st thing, change `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat + "," + lon);` to `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);`.

Comment: Great, thanks! But how do I make it add to the list, and not overwrite them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the map the first time store it in a somewhere where it's global accessible(e.g. as a global variable or a property of `document.getElementById('map')` ).

Inside `mezmerize` use the stored map instead of creating a new instance.

Demo(stores the Map-instance via `$('#map').data()`) :

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Lomf6v77/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Lomf6v77/)